# How can I assign one part of the WHERE clause to multiple other parts of it?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I would like to make a mysql query like: `SELECT * FROM something WHERE title LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR something LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' AND costs < '".$max."'`

This will give me all the results where title like search and the results for something like search AND costs smaller $max. But I want the costs < $max also for title like $search. But I dont want to put costs < $max two times into the script. So is there a way to assign it to both? Maybe with brackets: `WHERE (title LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR something LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%') AND costs < '".$max."'`

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!
phpheini

Comment: I would recommend you do not have '%string%' in your where clauses. It will work, but it will be very slow. I'd recommend looking at the Full-Text Search functionality offered by MySQL to help with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use parentheses so that the OR is evaluated first:

```
WHERE (title LIKE '%foo%' OR something LIKE '%foo%')
AND costs < '20'
```

Other remarks:

- I'd suggest that you escape your strings using [`mysql_string_real_escape`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL injection attacks. Or take a look at PDO and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
- You may also want to look at a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) as an alternative approach as this will be faster.

Comment: I'm just going to have to up-vote this even though the OP posted this solution as part of the question ;-)